# How to bind data from XElement to combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, combobox, xelement

XElement Doc.

```
<forms xmlns="">
  <form>
    <id>1361</id>
    <name>TEST3</name>
  </form>
  <form>
    <id>1658</id>
    <name>TEST4</name>
  </form>
  <form>
    <id>1975</id>
    <name>Mac New Patient</name>
  </form>
  <form>
    <id>2209</id>
    <name>Test Atlantic</name>
  </form>
  <form>
    <id>2565</id>
    <name>Rice Creek Test</name>
  </form>
</forms>
```

**Code behind**

```
 XElement xmlForms = data.GetXmlForm();
 var ElementsList = from c in xmlForms.Element("Forms").Descendants("form")
 select new { Name = c.Element("name").Value, ID = c.Element("id").Value };

 cBox_NewPat.DataContext = ElementsList; 
 cBox_NewPat.DisplayMemberPath = "name";
 cBox_NewPat.SelectedValuePath = "id";
```

I need to bind data(name, id) from XElement to WPF Combobox. For some reason, its not working, not even get the data from XML into the Element List.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: is really as simple as changing .Element("Forms") to .Element("forms")?

Comment: @Phil, sorry was my mistake, i meant to type "forms", but its not working,, returned null result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property names are case sensitive.

You need to change

```
cBox_NewPat.DisplayMemberPath = "name";
cBox_NewPat.SelectedValuePath = "id";
```

To

```
cBox_NewPat.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
cBox_NewPat.SelectedValuePath = "ID";
```

to match your anonymous type.

Comment: This is okay, its all in Lowercase.. i got a null exception when i run these codes

Comment: Sorry, you're right this was the only mistake. got it now Thank You for taking your time to responde

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing several things here (aside from the null result - I will get to it below).

1. you need to set ItemsSource property on the combobox.

   ```
   cBox_NewPat.ItemsSource = ElementsList
   ```
2. you should use

   ```
   cBox_NewPat.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   cBox_NewPat.DisplayMemberPath = "name";
   ```

   since your anonymous type property is called "Name", not "name". The same with SelectedValuePath
3. please show what you do in GetXmlForm method - this is where something goes wrong. If you do XElement.Parse(xmlString), then it will work if you remove the namespace attribute (xmlns) from the forms element. you will also need to use

   ```
   xmlForms.Descendants("form")
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   xmlForms.Element("forms").Descendants("form")
   ```